# How to use groundDb package in Ionic + angular application?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

I have an ionic + angular application and we have used Meteor DDP at server, at present we have created client side collection in minimongo database which is created in clientside memory. which gets clear when user removes application from memory.

I want support offline feature & persistent storage on client-side, so when application goes to offline mode it should display data from local database.

I found [GroundDB](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db) suits better in my project but the challenge is there no out of box GroundDB package to include in ionic project.

Do anyone have used GroundDB in ionic + angular project? if yes please share steps to include GroundDB.

I also know that Meteoric is the solution for this but I dont want to use Meteor for frontend, I want to use AngularJS.

Comment: since GroundDB is a wrapper around `Meteor.collections`, it won't work without Meteor.  You could try using [angular-meteor](https://github.com/urigo/angular-meteor/).

Comment: Hi @Claies, can you please give me steps to install meteor to Ionic-angular project? I think we tried the same but we have ionic project.

Comment: I've never personally used angular-meteor, but since ionic is a superset of angular, it should be fully compatible.